# bincode::encode_into_slice returns incorrect data

Tags: rust, bincode

I am using `bincode` crate(unstable version `2.0.0-rc.3`) to perform binary serialization and deserialization of structs(trying to perform C `memcpy` of structs without padding into a buffer). While performing `encode_into_slice` in `big endian` format, the amount of bytes written into a `[u8]` buff is incorrect when compared the total size of the struct.

```
use bincode::{Decode, Encode};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Default, Deserialize, Serialize, Decode, Encode, Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
// size of struct is 10
pub struct Data {
    pub u: u16,
    pub f: f64,
}

fn main() {
    let data = Data {
        u: 1111u16,
        f: 1111.0,
    };
    let mut buff = [0u8; 16];
    if let Ok(processed_len) = bincode::encode_into_slice(&data, &mut buff, bincode::config::standard().with_big_endian()) {
        // prints value of 9 for smaller field values and sometimes 11 for larger field values
        println!("{}", processed_len);
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
bincode = "2.0.0-rc.3"
serde = { version = "1.0.195", features = ["derive"] }
```

Comment: bincode doesn't do "memcpy without padding"

Comment: can you suggest an alternative way?

Comment: If you're looking for the fastest possible serialization format, there's rkyv: https://docs.rs/rkyv/latest/rkyv/ It is a bit complex but will give you the best performance. If you just want to save something in a small format, bincode works fine. Bincode has fixed-size integer encoding if you want a more predictable size. If you want the smallest possible serialization, save it to whatever format you want (bincode works) and then compress it.

Comment: got it fixed with the additional config `with_fixed_int_encoding()`